# How to export references from Endnote web to Endnote X5?

Tags: citations, reference-managers

I understand that Endnote X7 has the Sync feature to sync with the Endnote Web. But for some reason, the Sync is not working and my program is just getting stuck. So I have decided to use Endnote X5. But I do not know how to download the references from Endnote Web to Endnote X5. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **step-by-step guide**, provided on the [EndNote's Online Help page](http://www.myendnoteweb.com/help/ENW/hs_researchsoftexport.htm):

- Export references following the [export instructions](http://www.myendnoteweb.com/help/ENW/hsr_export.htm) using "RefMan (RIS) Export" as the export style;
- click the Save To... button and save the export file to your computer;
- open EndNote;
- open an existing or new library;
- select Import from the File menu;
- in the Import dialog, click Browse to select the export file;
- select "Reference Manager (RIS)" as the Import Option;
- for EndNote 8 or later, select "No Translation" as the Text Translation (not applicable in your case).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already tried this. But when I export it always seems to export a ".txt" file irrespective of which export style I choose from the list. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Yathi: You're welcome. RefMan (RIS) Export produces a text file, but with a corresponding internal structure. Try renaming the "<name>.txt" file to "<name>.ris" and then importing it.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Yathi: My pleasure! I'm glad it helped.